# Tkinter option menu widget add command lambda does not produce expected command

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda, tkinter, optionmenu

I am trying to create a window that has an optionmenu that is populated based on a fileselection dialog. I am able to make the optionmenu contain all options based on a previously selected file. However, no matter what option is selected by the user, the variable contains the last option that was read from the selected file.

I would love if someone can explain me why this happens. Therefore, I have included a minimal example below:

```
from Tkinter import *
Tk()

class App():

    chunks = ['A','B','C'] # These are read from a file in the actual program
    testVariable = StringVar()

    def __init__(self,master):

        def initSummary():
            self.dataButton["menu"].delete(0, 'end')
            for i in self.chunks:
                print i # To demonstrate what's in there
                self.dataButton["menu"].add_command(label=i, command = lambda: self.testVariable.set(i))

        top = self.top = Toplevel()
        top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: close(self))
        self.sumButton = Button(top, text="Test", width=25, command=lambda: initSummary())
        self.sumButton.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.dataButton = OptionMenu(top, self.testVariable, "Stuff")
        self.dataButton.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

# Call the main app
root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This code will show `C` on the optionmenu, regardless of what the user has selected, while the `print` in the code produces the expected `A`, `B` and `C`. I would understand if the `print` also showed 3 times `C` but the mismatch of what is printed and what is shown in the GUI is throwing me off.

Comment: That's a classical issue when using lambdas in for loops: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction @j_4321. I added an intermediate function to fix the mentioned problem, would you say that this is the 'correct' way of addressing such an issue?

Comment: I don't know if there is one 'correct' way to address this issue. I used to add an intermediate function like you, but now I prefer using `lambda j=i: self.testVariable.set(j)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue of the lambda in a for loop (thanks to @j_4321) by adding an intermediate function as shown in the below code.

```
from Tkinter import *

class App():

    chunks = ['A','B','C']

    def __init__(self,master):

        self.testVariable = StringVar()

        def refresh():
            # Prints what's in the variable
            print self.testVariable.get()

        def testFunc(x):
            return lambda: self.testVariable.set(x)

        def initSummary():
            self.dataButton["menu"].delete(0, 'end')
            for i in self.chunks:
                self.dataButton["menu"].add_command(label=i, command = testFunc(i))

        top = self.top = Toplevel()
        self.sumButton = Button(top, text="Test", width=25, command=lambda: initSummary())
        self.sumButton.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.dataButton = OptionMenu(top, self.testVariable, "Stuff")
        self.dataButton.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.testButton = Button(top, text="Variable", width=25, command = lambda: refresh())
        self.testButton.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

# Call the main app
root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Please comment if this is not the 'correct' way of addressing this issue.

Comment: `Tk() # Biggest mystery of Tkinter`: this is not a mystery, it's just that `testVariable = StringVar()` needs a master window. You should consider putting this inside `__init__`: `self.testVariable = StringVar()`, that way you won't need to create a window before declaring your class.

Comment: I always expected that the `root - Tk()` is responsible for the master window. Hence I was surprised that I need the additional `Tk()` when I was creating the example for this question. The application for which this question was created has no need for the additional `Tk()` as my `StringVars` are always inside an `__init__` as you mentioned.

Comment: @BasJansen: `Tk()` isn't _responsible_ for the master window, it _is_ the master window. You should not create two of them.

Comment: Noted. I have fixed the answer to be more in line with correct Tkinter usage.